# DataTable Data List with Related Column on Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, foreach

I have the below table in SQL:

```
 PARENT_CODE   CHILD_CODE   ATTRIBUTE_NAME  ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPT R_YEAR    
    ------------- ------------ --------------  ------------------ -----------
    1             001           ATT1            Description1       2016
    1             001           ATT2            Description2       2016
    1             001           ATT3            Description3       2016
    1             001           ATT4            Description4       2016
    1             001           ATT5            Description5       2016
    1             001           ATT6            Description6       2016
    1             002           ATT1            Description1       2016
    1             002           ATT2            Description2       2016
    1             002           ATT3            Description3       2016
    1             002           ATT4            Description4       2016
    2             003           ATT1            Description1       2016
    2             003           ATT2            Description2       2016
    2             003           ATT3            Description3       2016
    2             003           ATT4            Description4       2016
```

How can I show my output in the format below?

```
 1 - 001 :
  ATT1 : Description1  
  ATT2 : Description2  
  ATT3 : Description3  
  ATT4 : Description4  
  ATT5 : Description5  
  ATT6 : Description6
1 - 002 :    
  ATT1 : Description1  
  ATT2 : Description2  
  ATT3 : Description3  
  ATT4 : Description4   
2 - 003 :    
  ATT1 : Description1  
  ATT1 : Description2  
  ATT1 : Description3  
  ATT1 : Description4
```

I know we can use LinQ or foreach loop to get the result, but I do not have any idea how to proceed.

below my code :

```
string[] seledItems = ConvertLib.ToStr(Request.Form["sel_items[]"], string.Empty).Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string GetQUeryStr = string.Format(@"SELECT PARENT_CODE,CHILD_CODE,ATTRIBUTE_NAME,ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPT,R_YEAR FROM JOBPATTERN
                                     WHERE R_YEAR='{0}' AND PARENT_CODE IN ({1})", ddlYears.SelectedValue, string.Join(",", seledItems.Select(q => string.Format("'{0}'", q)).ToArray()));

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GetQUeryStr, conn))
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
         // then how can i  write this part
        }
     }
}
```

i`m added my code at above for  a reference.

Comment: It can be done with basic linq - have you looked into `GroupBy`? Please show what you have been trying and searching

Comment: i`m just want to do same parent id and same child id data group then show like that above

Comment: im have populate datatable with above data. then need to group .

Comment: already added my code on the question part.

Comment: use to ChildCode groped it same parent will be have a differend child. so, use to child_code need to group it

Answer (score 0):

By the format of the input you want I understand you want to group by multiple columns and for each key to have the list of matching items under it.

Using linq query syntax:

```
var result = (from item in dt
              group new { item.ATTRIBUTE_NAME, item.ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPT }
              by new { item.PARENT_CODE, item.CHILD_COD } into g
              select new 
              {
                  g.Key,
                  Items = g.ToList();
              });
```

In method syntax:

```
var result = dt.GroupBy(item => new { item.ATTRIBUTE_NAME, item.ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPT }
                        (key, group) => new 
                        { 
                            key, 
                            Items = group.Select(item => new { item.PARENT_CODE, item.CHILD_COD }).ToList()
                        });
```

Last but not least - please do not use string concatanation to build your sql queries. It is susceptible to SQL injection. Use Parameterized Queries instead